# Performance of " > ALL" VS "MAX()" in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample Table invoices

| invoice_total | client_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 |
| 3000 | 1 |
| 2500 | 3 |
| 50 | 3 |

Code-1

```sql
    SELECT * 
    FROM invoices
    WHERE invoice_total > (
     SELECT MAX (invoice_total)
     FROM invoices
     WHERE client_ID =3
    )
```

vs

Code-2

```sql
    SELECT * 
    FROM invoices
    WHERE invoice_total >  ALL (
     SELECT invoice_total
     FROM invoices
     WHERE client_ID =3
    )
```

I was going through some online SQL videos where the instructor said both are equivalent. Although both produce the same result, performance-wise isn't the code-1 better than code-2?

As far as I understand:
In the case of code-1 the DB is processed twice: once to get max() and second to get all values greater than the result of max(). Complexity = N+K

while in the case of code-2 each row is compared to the list of results from the subquery. Complexity = N*K.

Or does internal optimization take place and both have the same performance?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html

Comment: The optimizer may know that `> ALL()` is roughly equivalent to `> (SELECT MAX())` and produce a similar plan, rather than comparing to everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query 1

```
 Scan count 2, logical reads 2
---------------
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 13 ms.
---------------
Query Cost is 49%
```

sql optimizer use Inner Join for get result between subquery and outer query

Query 2

```
 Scan count 2, logical reads 5
---------------
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 159 ms.
---------------
Query Cost is 51%
```

sql optimizer use Left Join for get result between subquery and outer query

subquery cost in both of Queries are equal.
I think Query1 is better than Query2

Answer (score 5):

They do not produce the same result.

If there are no invoices for `client = 3`, then the `ALL` returns all rows.  The `MAX()` returns no rows.

As for performance, you should test on your database.  MySQL probably optimizes them similarly, but there could be differences because the meaning is different.